# Can't import a module in parent directory on App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Say I have a module called "test_module", but I want to import a file within the parent directory with this kind of folder structure:

```
/app_root
    __init__.py
    script_to_import.py

    /test_module
        test_script.py
```

Basically I want to be able to import "script_to_import.py" from "test_script.py". I added the following code to `test_script.py` in order to add the parent directory:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
```

However, I'm still getting a `"ImportError: No module named script_to_import"` error when I try to run `dev_appserver.py`. Any ideas how to add a parent directory to my python path for import?

Thanks!

Comment: First, make sure you have an `__init__.py` inside the `/test_module` directory.  Also, where is your `app.yaml` located?

Comment: There's an `__init__.py` in there. Also my `app.yaml` is in my `/app_root` directory.

Comment: If you can't get the python path stuff worked out, you might consider just creating a symlink to script_to_import.py in your /test_module directory.  Then you can import it as if it were local to the /test_module directory.  [How to create symlink](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-creating-symbolic-link-ln-command)